# webservice- converting odbc access connections to sql server

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, odbc

I'm trying to update my software from odbc connections to my new sql server.  The new sql connections are defaulting to the old database (see below code).  I've even tried to keep the odbc connections for sql and point to my new db, but the webservice is returning a boolean, not the soap.  The sql server is setup for and working on a newer webservice.  What am I missing?

Here is the old code:

```
<WebMethod()> Public Function LookupItem(ByVal strUPC As String) As DataSet
    Try
        Dim connUPC As New Odbc.OdbcConnection
        Dim ConnectionString As String
        Dim strSQL As String
        '//get upc info            
        strSQL = "SELECT Inv_Qty.*,PLU.*,PLU.PLU_NUM, PLU.DEPT_NUM From PLU INNER JOIN Inv_Qty ON PLU.PLU_NUM=Inv_Qty.PLU_NUM WHERE ((PLU.PLU_NUM) = '" & strUPC & "');"
        ConnectionString = "DSN=mainODBC"
        connUPC.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
        Dim cmdUPC As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(strSQL, connUPC)
        Dim dsUPC As DataSet = New DataSet
        Dim daUPC As Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(cmdUPC)
        connUPC.Open()
        daUPC.Fill(dsUPC, "TC")
        connUPC.Close()
        connUPC = Nothing
        Return dsUPC
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Function
```

I've tried to just change the connections:

```
<WebMethod()> Public Function LookupItem(ByVal strUPC As String) As DataSet
    Try
        Dim connUPC As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim ConnectionString As String
        Dim strSQL As String
         '//get upc info            
        strSQL = "SELECT Inv_Qty.*,PLU.*,PLU.PLU_NUM, PLU.DEPT_NUM From PLU INNER JOIN Inv_Qty ON PLU.PLU_NUM=Inv_Qty.PLU_NUM WHERE ((PLU.PLU_NUM) = '" & strUPC & "');"
         ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost\db;Initial Catalog=DB_SQL;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myID;Password=myPass"
        connUPC.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
         Dim cmdUPC As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSQL, connUPC)
        Dim dsUPC As DataSet = New DataSet
        Dim daUPC As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdUPC)
         connUPC.Open()
        daUPC.Fill(dsUPC, "TC")
        connUPC.Close()
        connUPC = Nothing
        Return dsUPC
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code and looking at the new `SqlClient` objects? That should give you a good idea of where things are going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way :)
Hope it helps...

```
    <WebMethod()> Public Function LookupItem(ByVal strUPC As String) As DataSet
    Try
        Dim connUPC As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim cmdUPC As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim daUPC As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dsUPC As DataSet = New DataSet
        Dim ConnectionString As String = "Data Source=localhost\db;Initial Catalog=DB_SQL;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myID;Password=myPass"
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT Inv_Qty.*,PLU.*,PLU.PLU_NUM, PLU.DEPT_NUM From PLU INNER JOIN Inv_Qty ON PLU.PLU_NUM=Inv_Qty.PLU_NUM WHERE ((PLU.PLU_NUM) = '" & strUPC & "');"

        '// Opening the connection
        connUPC.Open()
        cmdUPC.Connection = connUPC
        cmdUPC.CommandText = strSQL

        daUPC.SelectCommand = cmdUPC
        daUPC.Fill(dsUPC)

        connUPC.Close()
        connUPC = Nothing

        Return dsUPC
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Function
```

Have fun!

Comment: that looks like the same thing just organized better.